# Probability of ruin - calculating an integral after exponential change of measure

Tags: probability, integration, sampling

Let's consider a process $u - S_n$, where $S_n = Y_1 + \ldots + Y_n$ is a sum of iid random variables with the density $p(y)$. Let:

- $T_0 = \min\{n: u - S_n < 0 \}$,
- $T_b = \min \{n: u - S_n >b \}$ for $0 < u < b$,
- $T = \min \{T_0, T_b \}$.

We want to calculate $\psi = \mathbb{P}(T = T_0)$ using importance sampling (exponential change of measure).

We denote:
$$
R = \begin{cases}
\min\{n: S_n > u  \} &\text{if such n exists}, \\
\infty  &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

Therefore $\psi = \mathbb{P}(T = T_0) = \mathbb{P}(R < \infty).$

In order to define instrumental density we denote $q(y) = e^{ry}p(y).$

Let $\mathcal{R_n} = \{ (y_1, \ldots , y_n): y_1 \le u, y_1 > u- b, \ldots, y_1+...+y_{n-1} \le u, u-b > y_1 + \ldots + y_{n-1}, y_1 + \ldots +y_{n}>u, u-b > y_1 + \ldots + y_n   \}.$

Then the event $\{ R = n \} $ occurs when $(Y_1, \cdots, Y_n) \in \mathcal{R_n}$, so

$$
\mathbb{P}_p(R=n) = \int \int_{\mathcal{R}_n} \cdots\int p(y_1) \ldots p(y_n) dy_1 ... dy_n = \int \int_{\mathcal{R}_n} \cdots \int e^{-r y_1} q(y_1) \ldots e^{-r y_n}q(y_n) dy_1 \ldots dy_n=
$$
$$
= \int \int_{\mathcal{R}_n} \cdots \int e^{r (y_1 + \ldots + y_n)} q(y_1) \ldots q(y_n) dy_1 \ldots dy_n
$$

I wonder how to express the above integral interms of $\mathbb{E}_q$. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: a) I think the second $q(y_1)$ should be $q(y_n)$? b) You can get a properly spaced and aligned ellipsis using `\ldots` for an ellipsis on the baseline (e.g. between commads) and `\cdots` for a vertically centred ellipsis (e.g. between $+$ signs). c) Isn't this just $\mathbb E_q\left[\mathrm e^{r(y_1+\cdots+y_n)}\right]$? (It may be that I didn't understand the problem correctly.)

Comment: Yes, you are right :) I will correct that.